# implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'

Tags: android

**`ERROR: implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'`**

I am unable add firebase dependency while uisng

THIS DEPENDENCY..

```
implementation'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
```

Answer (score 3):

Just comment out this line `//noinspection GradleCompatible`

it worked for me with firebase:

[image]

Comment: How do you know that is the problem we are facing?

Answer (score 2):

In the dependencies change appcompact-v7:28.0.0-alpha3 to appcompact-v7:28.0.0-alpha1. Also you can use the previous version v7:27.0.1.

Answer (score 2):

This is because of conflicting dependency versions. try .`/gradlew app:dependencies`, you can find the culprit.

Answer (score 1):

use **latest version of firebase dependencies**, if there are any in the project

as included below

use implement

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:17.1.3'
```